# Missing path of css and js after url rewriting

Tags: asp-classic

In my asp classic web application. I have `url` rewriting like this

For example : `www.website.com/Tour/state/City`

Problem is that path of all css and js path is changed and could not adjust.

like : if we give path of `css` like

> www.website.com/css/style.css

Then on execution it will be like this

> www.website.com/Tour/www.website.com/css/style.css

Is any one have solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

give the path like this :

> /css/style.css